# Possible length of isosceles triangle side.

Tags: calculus, general-topology, algebra-precalculus, geometry, square-numbers

The perimeter of a right triangle $RST$ is equal to the perimeter of isoceles triangle $xyz$ The lengths of the legs of the right triangle are 6 and 8. If the length of each side of the isoceles triangle is an integer what is the greatest possible length for one of the sides of isoceles triangle $xyz$?

The hypotenuse of $RST$ is $\sqrt{100} = 10$

For $xyz$ let $xy = yz$ as the two equal legs, and $zx$ is the unequal, the "base" side.

Perimeter of $RST$ = $xyz$ = $24$

So leg $zx = 2$ is the **lowest** length the triangle can have, so that the other two are integers.

$xy + yz = 22 = 2xy \implies xy = 11 = yz$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Correct answer, correct reasoning.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Shaun Which part of "Is this correct?" did I fail to answer?

Comment: That was an automated reply; yes, it's an inappropriate one. I'm sorry. This answer was flagged as low quality due to its length. I agreed somewhat in my review, thinking that it'd be better off as a comment. Never mind :)